# Chart apps for django

Tags: django, charts

I'm building an application in django and I'd like to have a reports section. The charts will be used to disply numerical values between different dates.

I tried [GoogleChartWrapper](http://code.google.com/p/google-chartwrapper/) but I'm looking something more flexible and nicer.

Thanks.

Comment: If you need some library to help you generate your reports, you should take a look a [django-cube](http://code.google.com/p/django-cube/). It doesn't generate the graph for you, however it is meant for making calculation of the aggregations much easier (therefore it helps you provide data to the graph library you will use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a django question - just use a javascript plotting package and stick it in your django app in the usual way (.js goes into your media files, javascript includes go into your templates for headers etc). Then write django templates that dump your data into whatever the plot package needs - probably javascript.

I've used [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) for this, but for something really shiny there's [protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) which is something I might use next time!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking through different javascript chart packages but the ones I like have license for commercial use. Open-flash-chart(http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/gallery-pie.php) has pretty nice pie charts but i'm not sure about using flash in my app.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something powerful I suggest to take a look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/). This may be also useful: [matplotlib and Django](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Django).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to design a chart with e.g. http://dexautomation.com/googlechartgenerator.php and then maintain it and fill with real data using http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-chart-tools

Answer (score 1):

you could also try chartit (it uses highcharts).
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_chartit